# prototype.js and some other js's conflicts

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I don't know much things about javascript and i don't have any friends that knows javascript :( that's why im asking stackoverflow community again for help.
I've got a new template for my script but the problem is that i have some conflicts on the prototype.js that is required for my script to work with some js's from template and i dont know how to solve this problem, because the template wont work properly without comments js, main js and the script wont work properly without prototype js
I dont know if somebody has time to take a look in the scripts and maybe give a solution to merge them, because are big scripts, at last i will try.

I have uploaded the scripts on some locations and putted the links here

```
pastebin.com/n5dnr6i7 here is the main.js required for template

pastebin.com/YisnTuBM comments.js recuired for template

pastebin.com/Cibn1NA2 prototype.js required for main script
```

comments and main are not working properly with prototype loaded

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Im sorry for posting this in Java thanks for the correction

Edit 2: 
The problem is that the web script is encrypted with IonCube and i have access just to the template html files, it is a bit complicated because the template is for a modified/cracked verion of the web script that im using, it is a video tube script and for example the original web script that i have uses comments.html included in the video.html the cracked/modified is different and i had to include the old comments.html file in the new video.html template, now if i use jquery-1.9.1 the comment area box slide down as it should when i click it but i cant comment to the video if i use prototype i can comment to the video but the comment area box is frozen it doesent slide down when i click it, and i have no ideea how to merge them

Comment: _I don't know much things about java_ please remember Java != Javascript, they are different galaxies.

Comment: You indeed don't know much about Java. Java has nothing to do with JavaScript. It's a completely different language.

Comment: @Laura have you referenced prototype.js and comments.js and main.js in your html file?

Comment: What are you trying to do in general with these files? Is there any higher-level functionality you are trying to do?

Comment: Your best bet is to hand further development of your application over to a developer who has a better grasp of these concepts.  You will likely find client-side work very frustrating with a lack of understanding of basic concepts, such as the difference between java and javascript.

Comment: @RayNicholus That is the worst suggestion I've ever heard. You'd rather give up instead of trying to learn? How do you know they've worked with Java before and truly know what it is? What's it matter if they mistyped/mistagged the question with "Java"? They could easily be using a Java backend, and for some reason refer to the frontend as Java because of confusion or their own convention. They clearly have an understanding of Javascript. A little misunderstanding and/or mistyping does not warrant the suggestion to give up.

Comment: It would've been a lot more useful to explain there is a difference, point them in a direction to learn the difference, as well as provide stuff for them to learn about each language specifically, depending on what they really need. PradeepSimha's comment was more than enough as a warning to the OP that they might be confused with languages/names. It's tough as a beginner developer to get **everything** right...something the all mighty lords of StackOverflow often forget...

Comment: @Ian I think you're being a bit dramatic here.  Instead of complaining about how others did not provide links to learning materials and did not explain the differences between javascript and java, you could have done this yourself instead of derailing the topic.

Comment: @RayNicholus I didn't derail the topic at all. You seemed to think the topic was the difference between Java and Javascript. So I'm just staying on topic. A bit dramatic, sure. A bit necessary though, I'd say. And you're right, I could've provided resources/materials, but I don't have an obligation to answer every single question. I, as well as everyone, get to choose what I want to answer/say. For this question, I decided to **comment** on other comments. Fully valid on my part. Just like yours and others comments are valid. I just didn't agree with them, so I pointed it out.

Comment: Ok guys chill down, i corrected my mistake, from java to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added those files [to a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEEq9/1/), and are you sure Prototype is even required? I've commented it out and replaced with jQuery (as the comments file seems to require it, as does the combined [main] file).

After doing this I get no errors on page load.

```
<!-- prototype -->
<!--script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Cibn1NA2"></script-->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!--script>jQuery.noConflict();</script-->

<!-- comments -->
<script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YisnTuBM"></script>

<!-- main = Modernizr + extras -->
<script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=n5dnr6i7"></script>
```

**Edit for comments:** [Second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTExW/6/) to show a use of jQuery `noConflict()`:

The setup - either leave both script tags uncommented, or try commenting one or the other to see which errors you get.

The tests use the [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function of jQuery, and the [`addClassName`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/addClassName/index.html) function of Prototype in order to see which version of `$` is active. One or other of the methods will fail depending on which `$` is active at that time.

```
<!-- Comment one of these script tags, or leave both uncommented for noConflict mode -->
<!-- jQuery must come second in order to properly use noConflict -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

The tests:

```
// local var for jQuery - this might be undefined if jQuery not imported
var jQuery = window["jQuery"];
// if jQuery exists, put into noConflict mode - i.e. return jQuery $ to Prototype $
if (jQuery) jQuery.noConflict();

try {
    // addClassName is prototype only, not jquery
    $("output").addClassName("prototype");
    setOutput("$.addClassName ok");
} catch (e) {
    setOutput("Prototype > $.addClassName error: " + e);
}

try {
    // addClass is jquery only, not prototype
    $("output").addClass("jquery");
    setOutput("$.addClass ok");
} catch (e) {
    setOutput("jQuery > $.addClass error: " + e);
}

try {
    // try using jQuery with the 'full' jQuery name
    jQuery("output").addClass("jquery");
    setOutput("jQuery.addClass ok");
} catch (e) {
    setOutput("jQuery > jQuery.addClass error: " + e);
}

// wrap the code that needs $ to be jQuery $ in a function.
// and pass in jQuery to be aliased as $ within the function.
(function($) {
    try {
        $("output").addClass("jquery");
        setOutput("$.addClass ok when wrapped");
    } catch (e) {
        setOutput("jQuery > wrapped $.addClass error: " + e);
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Sample output when both Prototype and jQuery are included:

```
$.addClassName ok
jQuery > $.addClass error: TypeError: $(...).addClass is not a function
jQuery.addClass ok
$.addClass ok when wrapped
```

Comment: I have edited the main post because i cant post the comment for your solution

Comment: I've just read your edit, but I still can't find anywhere in the code you have provided where Prototype is required. It all looks like jQuery code to me. Do you have an errors printed to the console that you can share?

Comment: I think my question has no sense without showing the full web script that im using so this leaves me with 2 choices to chose cracked web version and use the new template or the original version that i payd for with the template i have now.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me but i think is to complicated to solve it from a singe question since is hard for me to formulate the right question because i don't know much thinks about javascript

Comment: Ok. jQuery *does* have a `noConflict` mode which can swap back the original value of `$` (as hinted at in my answer), but to use it correctly you would have to know where in your code `$` means jQuery and where `$` means Prototype.

Comment: Hmm, can you please give me one example so i can understand it? for example comments.js script is not working at all if i include prototype, it is jquery i think. Can you take a look and give me a example on this please?

Comment: This is the error i get in firebug when i have both loaded prototype and comment loaded TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: If you are combining jQuery and Prototype on the same page, you must put jQuery in noConflict mode, as @PaulGrime has stated.  See http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul Grime, i did it! im sorry but i cant rate the answer if that mathers

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. Maybe try and accept the answer some other time then, as it will help other readers see that your problem was solved, and mark the question as answered/solved.